# why does ```map``` work on array but ```find``` breaks the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working in React Native with a variable that has a value equal to an array of objects:

```
const list2020 = [

    {
        "monthId": "4",
        "monthName": "May",
        "firstEkadasi": {
            "jsDayOfWeek": "1",
            "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
            "dayInMonth": "4",
            "ekadasiName": "Mohini"
        },
        "secondEkadasi": {
            "jsDayOfWeek": "1",
            "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
            "dayInMonth": "18",
            "ekadasiName": "Apara"
        },
        "thirdEkadasi": {}
    },

    {
        "monthId": "5",
        "monthName": "June",
        "firstEkadasi": {
            "jsDayOfWeek": "2",
            "dayOfWeek": "Tuesday",
            "dayInMonth": "2",
            "ekadasiName": "Pandava Nirjala"
        },
        "secondEkadasi": {
            "jsDayOfWeek": "3",
            "dayOfWeek": "Wednesday",
            "dayInMonth": "17",
            "ekadasiName": "Yogini"
        },
        "thirdEkadasi": {}

    }
]
```

---

I have a function that maps over this array:

```
function TestingMyCode() {

  const getCurrentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  let plusOne = getCurrentMonth + 1

  let currentMonthIndex = list2020.findIndex((list2020) => list2020.monthId == getCurrentMonth);
  let nextMonthIndex = currentMonthIndex + 1;

  return (
    list2020.find((list, index, array) => {
      if (list.thirdEkadasi.dayOfWeek == undefined) {
        return (
          <View key={index}>
            <Text style={styles.displayEkadasi}>{return-values-of-next-object-in-array (I want to return the values of the next month)}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }

    })
  )
}
```

---

When I use `list2020.map` I can get a result (even though it is not the desired result). 
However, when I used `list2020.find` it breaks the app with an error
`Objects are not valid as a React Child (found: object with keys {monthID, monthName,...}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`

Is there a vanilla JavaScript way of fixing this?

---

My objective is to display the values from the next object in the array (if the current object in array does not meet criteria:

1. If the current Month and date (which is May 19) is greater than the dates in the object
2. show the values from the next month (June)
3. Since the date is after May 18th, my app is not showing any text. I could easily display text with `if(data.monthId == month && data.firstEkadasi.dayInMonth >= dayOfMonth) {<Text>display text</Text>}`
4. But I am stuck if the `dayInMonth` is less than current date. For example, it's May 19 and the object at `index 0` has two Ekadasi dates; but both dates are less than 19.

---

How can I display the values from the next objects in the array?

---

[You can view repo of my code here](https://github.com/dominick-designs/react-native-app-ekadasi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `Array.prototype.find` is `arr.find(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])` and the callback function should return Boolean(true/false).

The `find()` method returns the value of the `first element` in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

You should use the `filter()` method instead of `find()` to display all values that meet the criteria.

so you should use

```
return (
    list2020.filter((list) => list.thirdEkadasi.dayOfWeek == undefined)
    .map((item) => 
          <View key={index}>
            <Text style={styles.displayEkadasi}>{return-values-of-next-object-in-array (I want to return the values of the next month)}</Text>
          </View>);
  );
```

So what you want to do will be like this:

```
const newList2020 = list2020.map((item) => ({ 
        monthId: item.monthId, 
        monthName: item.monthName, 
        ekadasi: [
            item.firstEkadasi, 
            item.secondEkadasi, 
            item.thirdEkadasi
        ]
    }); 

const thisMonth = new Date().getMonth();
const todayDate = new Date().getDate();

newList2020.filter(item => (
    item.ekadasi.find(ekadasi => 
        item.monthId > thisMonth 
        || (item.monthId === thisMonth && ekadasi.dayInMonth >= todayDate)
    ) !== undefined
)).map((item, index) => 
    <View key={index}>
        <Text style={styles.displayEkadasi}>{return-values-of-next-object-in-array (I want to return the values of the next month)}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, ```.map``` still gives me a full list of values from all of the items in the array. I only want to display the values from the next month. You can view the live demo of [this react native app here](https://dominick-designs.github.io/react-native-app-ekadasi/). As you can see it is not showing anything because the next Ekadasi is in June. Since there are no more dates in May that meet the criteria nothing is displayed. I want to be able to display values from June only. Thank you again.

Comment: So you want to display Ekadashis that is in the future, right?

Comment: First of all, you need to change the structure. I would recommend to include the Ekadasis as an array, not such objects first, second, third.
for this
```const newList2020 = list2020.map((item) => ({ monthId: item.monthId, monthName: item.monthName, ekadasi: [item.firstEkadasi, item.secondEkadasi, item.thirdEkadasi]});```
then you can set filter as follows
```newList2020.filter(item => (item.ekadasi.find(ekadasi => item.monthId > thisMonth || (item.monthId === thisMonth && ekadasi.dayInMonth >= todayDate) !== undefined))```
thisMonth and todayDate is month and dateInMonth of today

Comment: Now, you should display the filtered result.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up @Ever Dev now I am confused. Can you edit the answer so I know exactly where to put this code? The way I have it set up I have two ```returns``` one ```return``` is inside of the ```.map``` method; but I am confused with your most recent comment. Can you edit the answer? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was inspired by your mention of ```.find```  I ended up creating a separate ```.find``` variable like this:  ```const mylist = list2020.find(function listItems(element, index) {
    return element.monthId == month + 1
  })```  then I called this ```if(currentMonth === thisMonth && thirdEkadasi.dayInMonth == undefined)```   This works because the value of ```.find``` is thisMonth+1.  I was confused on how ```.find``` works. It grabs the object that meets that criteria. I was confused on which variable to use to display the results of my ```.find``` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is FIND expects a callback function, not just an item. In a way, it's very much like FILTER.

The following example is from MDN docs

```
const inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

const result = inventory.find( ({ name }) => name === 'cherries' );

console.log(result) // { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

So you need to rewrite your => line.